# CakePHP model to web service

Tags: web-services, rest, cakephp, cakephp-2.3, cakephp-model

I'm developing a web application that doesn't need database. All data comes via REST.

My question is: Is possible to use a model class (extended from AppModel) to manage data from a RESTfull service?, How to do that?, Does CakePHP any way to mapping directly a RESTfull web service?.

I have researched and I have found the $useTable attribute (http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#usetable) but I'm not sure if exists another way to do this in a better way.

My first idea is implement my own functions in a Model and put $useTable to false.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such functionality that ships with CakePHP, but it's relatively easy to implement it on your own.

Check out [datasources](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/datasources.html), they sit between the model and the data, but can also be used standalone, ie you can use [datasource instances](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-ConnectionManager.html#_getDataSource) directly, or indirectly through the model layer (find/save/delete calls are using the datasource CRUD methods).

Checkout https://github.com/nodesagency/CakePHP-Rest-Datasource for some inspiration.